# Filter out Sponsored feed on FB using uBlockOrigin

Tags: facebook, ublock-origin, ublock

How to block or filter this tricky "Sponsored" feed:
[image]

Html is as follows:

[image]

Previously I have used `has-text` filter:

```
##[id^=hyperfeed_story]:has-text(/Page Stories You May Like/)
```

But in this case this rule isn't working.
Is it possible to apply logic operators to filters? For instance,

```
has(span:has-text(/Sp/) AND
has(span:has-text(/on/)
```

PS. What lang is used by uBO filter?

Answer (score -1):

Use the following filter:

```
www.facebook.com##.userContentWrapper._5pcr > div:has(.r_zjlob1xpb)
```

Comment: could you please explain - how it works?

Comment: Won't help much, because the ID changes for each ad.